# Localize ContextMenu item header in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a UserControl that uses localized strings from resources. It works fine for all elements apart from ContextMenu items:

```
xmlns:Properties="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.Properties"
```

This works fine:

```
<Button Content="{x:Static Properties:Resources.BtnOpen}" ...
```

But this doesn't:

```
<TextBlock.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Header="{x:Static Properties:Resources.CmdClose}"
```

I'm getting: The member "CmdClose" is not recognized or is not accessible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is giving this error because the access modifier(protection level) may be '**internal**' make it to '**public**' in **Resources.Designer.cs** file

Its working in my case:

```
 <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
     <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Header="{x:Static resx:Resources.Total_Qty}" />
     </ContextMenu>
 </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
```

I made a property Total_Qty in my resource file.

Comment: it is already public and I can access it with no problems in other controls